# How can I delete <93> <94> symbols in file? It is equivalent " "

Tags: bash, shell-script, vi

I copied text from a PDF file in bash - `vi` 
and I get lines like this:

```
echo <93>The Hypotenuse is $hypotenuse<94>
```

I tried to change that in `vi` by:

```
s/<93>/"/g
```

But:

```
E486: Pattern not found: <93>
```

And by `sed`:

```
sed 's/'`echo "\093"`'/"/g' par.sh
```

And:

```
sed 's/'`echo "\094"`'/"/g' par.sh
```

And:

```
sed 's/\<93\>/\"/g' aa.sh
echo В“The Hypotenuse is $hypotenuseВ”
```

Could you tell me what I should use?

Comment: Your `vi` approach should have worked. If it didn't, you have non-printing characters. Could you show us the actual file?

Comment: If you are using a terminal emulator that supports colors, make sure that the `<93>` stuffs are not colored in `vi`. If they are, they must be hex-encoded unprintable characters. And your approach using `echo` is badly wrong -- You should use `-e` for backslash escapes, and `\0oo` is actually octal. The final resulting command would be `sed -i.bak -e s/[$(echo -e '\x93')$(echo -e '\x94')]/\"/g par.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

In **vi** you need to enter the key sequence for each of the 2 special characters, not the ascii chars for their display (if you place the cursor on them you'll see the entire ascii sequence is highlighted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>,
  <kbd>3</kbd> instead of `<93>`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>,
  <kbd>4</kbd> instead of `<94>`

So the search cmd would look something like this:

:%s /<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>,
   <kbd>3</kbd>/"/g

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you can use literal characters:

```
sed -e 's/”/"/g' -e 's/“/"/g' file
```

or using `perl` with Unicode code point:

```
perl -CSD -pe 's/\x{201C}|\x{201D}/"/g' file
```

Comment: $ sed -e 's/”/"/g' -e 's/“/"/g' aa.sh > a.sh
$ more a.sh 
echo В"The Hypotenuse is $hypotenuseВ"

Comment: @avsun: So does it work for you?

Comment: I have success with it only in vi, by sed I have an issue because <93> in sed looks like B”

Answer (score 0):

#### This is another way but using perl.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' file
```

- The -i flag creates a backup of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question in StackOverflow, this solution worked:

iconv -f cp1252 -t utf8 inputfile.csv > outputfile.csv

Short explanation- the characters are coming in cp1252 encoding, you can convert it to utf8.

Comment: Please consider adding a link to the SO question/answer, to help the OP and other readers fully understand.